# Python win32 Library 'The handle is invalid' error using SetConsoleCursorPosition

Tags: python, pywin32, handle

I am new somewhat new to Python coding and I need to use win32 library for output. I want to set consoleCursor to 0,0 but doesn't seem to work. I am trying to base this on what I would do for C++ programming.

```
c = win32console.PyCOORDType(0, 0)
hand = win32console.GetStdHandle(win32console.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
hand.SetConsoleCursorPosition(c)
```

hand is a PyConsoleScreenBuffer data type. I have tried casting it to HANDLE type but there is no function for SetConsoleCursorPosition with HANDLE type so PyConsoleScreenBuffer must be used.

Exact error returned
`pywintypes.error: (6, 'SetConsoleCursorPosition', 'The handle is invalid.')`

Comment: I guess over there in windows land y'all can't send `ESC CSI n ; m H` and be done with it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences

Comment: Worked for me from the interpreter terminal (I was able to mess it up). :)